# I'm trying to convert Pandas dataframe to HuggingFace DatasetDic

Tags: dataset, huggingface-transformers, tensorflow-datasets, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I have a pandas dataframe with 20k rows containing 2 columns named English, te. Changed the English column name to en. Trying to split the dataset into train, validation and test. And, I want to convert that dataset into

```
raw_datasets
```

the output i'm expecting is

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 18000
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 1000
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 1000
    })
})
```

I'm trying to write a code like `raw_datasets["train"][0]`, then it should return output like below

```
{'translation': {'en': 'Membership of Parliament: see Minutes',
  'to': 'Componenţa Parlamentului: a se vedea procesul-verbal'}}
```

The data must be in DatasetDict, similar to if we load data from huggingface like dataset DatasetDict type. Below is the code i've written but it's not working

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple

Dataset = namedtuple('Dataset', ['features', 'num_rows'])
DatasetDict = namedtuple('DatasetDict', ['train', 'validation', 'test'])

def create_dataset_dict(df):
    # Rename the column
    df = df.rename(columns={'English': 'en'})
    # Split the data into train, validation and test
    train_df = df.iloc[:18000, :]
    validation_df = df.iloc[18000:19000, :]
    test_df = df.iloc[19000:, :]
    # Create the dataset dictionaries
    train = Dataset(features=['translation'], num_rows=18000)
    validation = Dataset(features=['translation'], num_rows=1000)
    test = Dataset(features=['translation'], num_rows=1052)
    # Create the final dataset dictionary
    datasets = DatasetDict(train=train, validation=validation, test=test)
    return datasets

def preprocess_dataset(df):
    df = df.rename(columns={'English': 'en'})
    train_df = df.iloc[:18000, :]
    validation_df = df.iloc[18000:19000, :]
    test_df = df.iloc[19000:, :]
    train_dict = [{'translation': {'en': row['en'], 'te': row['te']}} for _, row in train_df.iterrows()]
    validation_dict = [{'translation': {'en': row['en'], 'te': row['te']}} for _, row in validation_df.iterrows()]
    test_dict = [{'translation': {'en': row['en'], 'te': row['te']}} for _, row in test_df.iterrows()]
    return DatasetDict(train=train_dict, validation=validation_dict, test=test_dict)

df = pd.read_csv('eng-to-te.csv')
raw_datasets = preprocess_dataset(df)
```

The above code is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/from-datasets-import-datasetdict (hope that helps!)

Comment: BTW, you also don't need to convert between versions if you use something like a csv reading in datasets, see https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/mixing-datasets-for-multi-x-huggingface-training

Answer (score 0):

Converting between formats might be expensive and not scalable. If the original data are some sort of parallel text files, e.g. `tatoeba-swe-deu.tsv`

```
Vi trodde att det var ett flygande tefat.   Wir hielten es für eine fliegende Untertasse.
Detta är huset jag bodde i när jag var barn.    Das ist das Haus, in dem ich als Kind gewohnt habe.
Vi hade roligt på stranden igår.    Gestern hatten wir am Strand viel Spaß.
Jag spelade tennis hela dagen.  Ich spielte den ganzen Tag Tennis.
Han vande sig kvickt vid det kalla vädret.  Er gewöhnte sich schnell an das kalte Wetter.
Kan du simma lika snabbt som honom? Kannst du genauso schnell wie er schwimmen?
Han är inte läkare. Er ist kein Arzt.
Åh nej! Mitt hus brinner!   Oh weh! Mein Haus brennt!
Jag trodde aldrig att ett såhär fint hotell skulle finnas på en sådan här plats.    Ich hätte nie gedacht, dass es an so einem Ort ein so schönes Hotel gibt.
Detta är deras hus. Das ist ihr Haus.
```

You can try:

```
ds = load_dataset("csv", data_files=["tatoeba-swe-deu.tsv"], 
         header=None, names=['SRC', 'TRG'], delimiter="\t", 
         encoding="utf8")

ds.train_test_split(test_size=0.1)
```

[out]:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['SRC', 'TRG'],
        num_rows: 9000000
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['SRC', 'TRG'],
        num_rows: 1000000
    })
})
```

**Note:**

- You can change the `names=['SRC', 'TRG']` to the headers that you need, e.g. `names=['en', 'to']`

Take a look at these for more examples:

- https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/from-datasets-import-datasetdict
- https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/mixing-datasets-for-multi-x-huggingface-training